# Pyinstaller app can't find my generated files

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, generate

I've created a Web interface where you upload CSV files, and as an output, a file is generated and downloaded from the browser.
Locally, everything works fine, the file is generated in the same folder as the code. But from my app.exe, I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file cannot be found: 'C:\Users\XXX\\AppData\Local\\Temp\\_MEI64842\results.xlsx'
```

How can I change the path to the generated file?
Thanks

I tried with another library cx_Freeze but the problem is the same, it's looking for the generated files in another folder in the Temp folder